# How to include link in handlebars template

Tags: email, templates, handlebars.js

I am using handlebars for my email templates. I am trying to include a link tag:

`In the meantime, please feel free to browse our product listing <a href="localhost:3000/products">here</a>`

However, once the email reaches the user, `here` is just plain text, not a link. Can someone help me fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you showing the result or the code of your template, if you are showing the code where are the {{ }} ?

Comment: I am showing the actual code. There are no {{ }} because I didn't include any variables. In my email, `here` does not show up as a link as it should since I wrapped it in `<a>` tags in the template

Comment: Maybe this is related to your email client that blocks the links. Try to have a look to the resulting source of the email and see if there is a link. If not that is not related to handlebar as it doesn't parse links. Try to dump the result before sending the email this will help you to point where your link disappear.